# How to print out every other letter in a word? (Java)

Tags: java

I have this assignment and I have to make it look like this:

Write a word: Hello World!

The result should be: HloWrd

And I just don't know which code to use so that the program will print out every other letter in a word.

Thanks, Eva

Comment: Show us your attempt, the community is not responsible for your homeworks.

Comment: If you show your attempt, we'll have a much better idea of what you could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to analyze the problem you have there. Given:

Hello World!

you need to have an output that is:

HloWrd

There is many ways of tackle down a problem like this, and no, I will not provide the code, but I will provide you something better, an analysis that may help you with this and future problems.

We can think that exists a pointer, that is pointing to the first letter (with index 0) and that is capable of reading this letter. Then all you would have to do is to print all letters that belongs to even positions (0, 2, 4 ...). Then you have to make this pointer iterate over the string. Let's see:

```
H -> 0
e -> 1
l -> 2
l -> 3
o -> 4
_ -> 5
W -> 6
o -> 7
r -> 8
l -> 9
d -> 10
! -> 11
```

So, in the first iteration, the pointer is pointing to the position 0. 0 is an even number, therefore we print it out (or store it, or whichever is your decision for the output). Then we increment the pointer to 1. As long as 1 is an odd number, we do not print it out. Then we proceed until there is no more letters in this chain.

Do you come up with any way you could build this now?

Take into consideration loops (for, while) to implement your solution. Once you have it, you can share it again and we can help you further with your learning process.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is the first time I've seen an answer to one of these "do my homework" questions that doesn't throw the answer at them. Good job for making it informative and thought-provoking. --- On a side note... incrementing the pointer by 2 each time is way better than checking each index to see if it's even or odd.

Comment: Thanks :) And yes, it may be.. I think I sometimes think too weird :P